# Multivariable chain rule for a pair of implicit equation

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, chain-rule

This is one of the questions we were asked in our iniversity examinations.

Find $\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)_y$  for the system:
\begin{align}
\begin{cases}
x+y^3+u^3+v^3=0\\
x^3+y-u^4-v^4=0
\end{cases}
\end{align}
Looking at the system we can say there will be two dependent variables. Since $x$ and $y$ are independent variables as specified in the question, $u$ and $v$ will be considered as dependent variables.

I have figured out two ways through which the problem can be approached.

a) Eliminate $v$. Partially differentiate the expression containing $u$, $x$ and $y$ w.r.t $x$ treating $y$ as constant and get the answer.

b) Partially differentiate both the equations w.r.t $x$ treating $y$ as constant. Now eliminate $\left(\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}\right)_y$ and get the required answer.

What i am not able to figure out is how to draw the dependency diagram (tree diagram) and write the chain rule for the given system. Kindly help by generalizing as to how to write the formula of chain rule for a system of implicit equations.

Comment: What is $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$ with index $y$? Do you mean, that argument for $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$ is $(x,y)$ or something else?

Comment: There are two dependent variables and two independent variables in the given system. Had the question just mentioned delu/delx it would have meant u is a dependent variable and x is an independent variable thus leaving room for confusion about the nature of the other two variables. (Delu/delx)y basically means u is a dependent variable and x and y are dependent variables.

Comment: Possibly related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2875041/implicit-function-theorem-to-solve-frac-partial-u-partial-x-when-f-bigx/

Comment: Thanks a lot. Indeed, it's related.

Comment: x and y are independent variables*

Answer (score 1):

Having system
$$\begin{cases}
x+y^3+u^3+v^3 = 0 & \\
x^3+y-u^4-v^4 = 0
\end{cases}$$
and differentiate each equation by $x$, assuming $u=u(x,y)$ and $v=v(x,y)$, we obtain
$$\begin{cases}
1+3u^2u'_x+3v^2v'_x = 0 & \\
3x^2-4u^3u'_x-4v^3v'_x = 0
\end{cases}$$
Now we have system of two linear equations with respect to variables $u'_x$ and $v'_x$, which can be solved by well known formulas in appropriate conditions.

For general case let's assume, that we have mapping $F$ continuous in neighborhood $W$ of the point $(x_0, y_0)\in \mathbb{R}^m\times \mathbb{R}^n$,  with values in $\mathbb{R}^m$ and with continuous partial derivative $F'_y(x,y)$ in it. If $F(x_0, y_0)=0$ and there exists $(F'_y(x_0,y_0))^{-1}$ and $|| (F'_y(x_0,y_0))^{-1}||<\infty$, then there exists neighborhood $U=U(x_0)$ and neighborhood $V=V(y_0)$ and function $f\colon U \to V$, continuous at $x_0$, such that $U \times V \subset W$ and $(F(x,y)=0 \text{ within }U \times V) \Leftrightarrow (y=f(x),x \in U)$. If in addition we know, that $F$ is differentiable at the point $(x_0,y_0)$, then the implicit function is also differentiable at the point $x_0$ and holds
$$f'(x_0)=-(F'_y(x_0,y_0))^{-1}F'_x(x_0,y_0)$$
More details and proofs you can find, for example, in Vladimir A. Zorich - Mathematical Analysis I-Springer, 2016, pages 595-597, or on [Implicit function theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem) in section "Statement of the theorem"  in formula for $\frac{\partial g}{\partial x_j}$.

Comment: I have already mentioned about this method. I want to know how to use the chain rule here.

Comment: Do you mean to write general form?

Comment: What we refer to as the chain rule here is a direct formula which takes into account the dependency between variables  and is used to find partial derivatives in cases where we have more than 1 equation.

Comment: @chemophilic that is the chain rule.

Comment: Like take the system u=x+y+z x=e^tsink, y=e^tcosk, z=e^t. Now we are asked to find delu/del t..then delu/delt=(delu/delx)(delx/delt)+(delu/dely)(dely/delt)+(delu/delz)dz/dt. This kind of direct formula is what i mean by chain rule

Comment: @chemophilic. Let me little time, I'll write direct general formula, but in your concrete case it will coincide with brought  solution of linear system.

Comment: @chemophilic. Wrote as promised. Write, please, if/when something find unclear.